# drop down on navbar is underneath the other components

Tags: css, vue.js, dropdown, nuxt.js

I am using the nuxt.js and I have a fixed header which I have a drop-down for changing the languages, but the problem is as I have set a height for header component when I click on the dropdown button it only shows up to that height
you can find the image to problem here:
https://ufile.io/g7tosuph

I have tried giving position: absolute to the drop-down items and also z-index of 9999 but no luck it is still underneath the other components in every page I have also made sure that the styles are note scoped in the .vue files

```css
.header-whole {
  background-color: #0e1e25;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 70px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
}

.lang-items {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: the lang-item refers to the items in the navbar of the languages which I get them from the Backend and store them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide some sample code?

I guess you have set your `<header>` position to "fixed", try to set your `<header>` z-index a z-index value, as well (greater than the `<main>` z-index value, if any).

Comment: yes I have set the header's position to be fixed and the z-index of the drop-down is greater than the header as well
I will edit the post and add some code

Comment: "overflow: hidden;" will not let any element inside your ".header-whole" elements be visible out of your ".header-whole" elements.

So, this is why your ".lang-items" dropdown menu will not show up complete.

Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow